# Hiding login panel in master page when users logged in. (ASP.net)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I have a panel in my master page that has textboxes for users login. Users logged in successfully but I want to hide panel .when users entered when I try to hide hide panel by false the visibility this doesn't work. My codes in master pages below: ( I use forms authentication and users are in data base)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hide panel doesn't work
    Panel1.Visible = false;
    //
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string str = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\ava\\Desktop\\WebSite3\\App_Data\\news.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where username=@name and pass=@pass";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", user.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", pass.Text);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Text, true);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Text, true);
        Response.Redirect("/website3/karbar/karbar.aspx");


    }
    else user.Text = "Incorrect name or pass";
}
```

Comment: dude! are you serious about keeping password in plain text !!!

Comment: So much anti-patterns here... plus serious security vulnerability. I think this Panel is not your major issue... Is it some kind of provocation? I only hope this is purely testing environment.

Comment: this is test , I encrypt this password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your master page after load is complete do following

```
if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
}
```

Or use LoginView this control supports template for both Anonymous and LoggedIn users

Comment: mind this will work only after the first redirect after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Panel1.Dispose();
```

Comment: I want to hide this panel and show another panel for logged in user. but this panel didn't hide and that panel didn't show . visibility of these panel doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, may help for you

```
Panel1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are writing the code in an aspx.cs page which is basically inherited that Master Page.

So you need to do in this way :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   ((Panel)YourMasterPageID.FindControl("YourPanelID")).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Or if you need to write the code inside the masterpage itself then you can write as: `code` YourPanelId.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none"); `code` OR `code` YourPanelId.Style.Add("display", "none"); `code`